# Jquery UI Tabs, how do you perform page navigation without ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

How can you perform page navigation with Jquery tabs without the ajax events firing? Following the tutorial, I added

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  select: function (event, ui) {
      var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
      if (url) {
        location.href = url;
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  });
```

And I added hrefs to the tabs going to other pages. The problem is, I have ajax used on the page and onload it posts to the url with an ajax call. I was hoping to disable ajax altogether for the tabs and just use them for straight navigation so I can leverage the styles.

Comment: I suggest to use .load() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently implemented jquery tabs, but modified it to suit my own needs. Basically all it is now is a formatted unordered list, and I change the CSS of the selected tab whenever it is clicked. Then the normal 'a' tag click event handles the href get. This is my Javascript and HTML:

```
function tabClickEvent() {
    $('div.nav ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
        $('div.nav ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
}

<div class="nav">
    <ul class="tabNavigation">
        <li class="tabbutton"><a href="<%= Url.RouteUrl("main") %>" id="all">all</a></li> 
        <li class="tabbutton"><a href="<%= Url.RouteUrl("wants") %>" id="wants">wants</a></li> 
        <li class="tabbutton"><a href="<%= Url.RouteUrl("needs") %>" id="needs">needs</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```